# Insert <br /> in a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say, I have a pretty long compund String:

```
var result = string1 + " - " + string2 + " - " + string3;
```

and I display the String in the Website by creating a new list item:

```
var listElement = document.createElement("li"),
container = document.querySelector("#resultlist"); //I have a <ul id="resultlist">
listElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result));
container.appendChild(listElement);
```

How can I add a `<br />` tag between e.g. the second and the third part of the String? So, I need something like this:

```
result = string1 + " - " + string2 + " <br /> " + string3;
```

(But that attempt just displays the tag).
I also tried the \n command already, but this had no effect on the website output.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're creating a text node. Try creating an element, and set its `innerHTML` property through Javascript. Also `#` is for *id* `.` is for *css classes*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: Another thing to try is wrapping your result in a span: `result = "<span>" + string1 + " - " + string2 + " <br/> " + string3 + "</span>"`

Comment: Read what you're writing. "create **Text** Node". HTML is not text!

Comment: Okay so how do I have to change the code?

Comment: Create two text nodes, one for each line. Append the first text node, then a `br` element, then the second text node.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that works fine!

Answer (score 2):

The `<br />` tag is HTML (at least you want it to be interpreted as HTML). You cannot add HTML to pages using `createTextNode()`, as the name suggests. You should use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
var result = "First String" + " - " + "Second String" + " <br /> " + "Third String",
listElement = document.createElement("li"),
container = document.querySelector("#resultlist"); //I have a <ul id="resultlist">
listElement.innerHTML = result;
container.appendChild(listElement);
```

```html
<ul id="resultlist"></ul>
```

Comment: This isn't the same if `string1`, etc. contain HTML tags. The original code will display them literally.

Comment: <br /> can't be used in the string.
You have to use \n or something else.

Comment: @Sandokan did you test that? \n is not something meaningful in HTML. If you mean that you have to escape the characters, that is not true. Only backslashes ( \ ) need to be escaped.