# Inserting <br /> in ReactJS iteration

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to fill up a Dialog Box with data from a `.json` file. Here is a single element of the data that is provided.

```
   {
      "type": "GP",
      "properties": {
        //other information
        "DR_NAME": "Dr Philips",
        "ALL_OPENING_HOURS": [
          {
            "day_string": "Monday - Thursday",
            "opening_hours": [
              "8.30AM – 12.30PM",
              "2.00PM – 4.30PM",
              "6.30PM – 9.00PM"
            ]
          },
          {
            "day_string": "Friday",
            "opening_hours": [
              "8.30AM – 12.30PM",
              "2.00PM – 4.30PM"
            ]
          },
          {
            "day_string": "Saturday & Sunday",
            "opening_hours": [
              "8.30AM – 12.30PM"
            ]
          },
          {
            "day_string": "Public Holiday",
            "opening_hours": [
              "Closed"
            ]
          }
        ],

        "FILE_NAME": "Slide1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          103.77076830515,
          1.38358044593591,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
```

I am currently writing a ReactApp, and I learnt to write JS code wrapped in HTML elements. I intended to put a new line/ line break after each pair of `day_string-opening_hours`, so that the final HTML generated will be as follows

**Expected output**

```
Opening Hours:

Monday - Thursday: 
8.30AM – 12.30PM, 2.00PM – 4.30PM, 6.30PM – 9.00PM, 

Friday: 
8.30AM – 12.30PM, 2.00PM – 4.30PM, 

Saturday & Sunday: 
8.30AM – 12.30PM, 

Public Holiday: 
Closed
```

However, this solution doesn’t work, and still shows each `day_string-opening_hours` being concatenated consecutively after one another

**Actual output:**

`Opening Hours:Monday - Thursday: 8.30AM – 12.30PM, 2.00PM – 4.30PM, 6.30PM – 9.00PM, Friday: 8.30AM – 12.30PM, 2.00PM – 4.30PM, Saturday & Sunday: 8.30AM – 12.30PM, Public Holiday: Closed`

I’m thinking about inserting a `<br />` after pair instead, but I’m not sure how to write HTML code wrapped in JS, even after seeing this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727038/insert-br-in-a-string-in-javascript). Does anyone know the solution to my problem? Here’s the relevant snippet of code.

```
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleToggle}>
  <DialogContent>
    //other information

    <hr />
    Opening Hours:
    {clinic.properties.ALL_OPENING_HOURS.map(period => (
      period.day_string+":\n"+period.opening_hours.join(",\n")
    ))
    .join(", \n")}
    <hr />

    //other information
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

**Update 1**

```
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleToggle}>
  <DialogContent>
    //other information

    <hr />
        <p>Opening Hours:</p>

        {clinic.properties.ALL_OPENING_HOURS.map(period => (
          <p>
          {period.day_string+":"}<br />{period.opening_hours.join(", ")}
          </p>
        ))
        .join(", \n")}
    <hr />

    //other information
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React converts the text you render the text that you map through the arrow function to html elements. As in html, if you just write text in several lines without line breaks(`<br/>`) it will take them as single line.

Best solution for you here is covering the text with paragraph tags.

```
<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleToggle}>
  <DialogContent>
    //other information

    <hr />
    <p>Opening Hours:</p>
    {clinic.properties.ALL_OPENING_HOURS.map(period => (
      <p>
        {period.day_string} :
        <br />
        {period.opening_hours.join(", ")}
      </p>
    ))}
    <hr />

    //other information
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Here is the Link for working stackblitz - [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eatfki)

[image: Edit infallible-sound-ss2dk]

Comment: I have tried adapting your solution to my code. However it doesn't work and instead the actual output becomes `[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can achieve what you want without break html tag.

```
return (
      <div>
        <h3>Openning Hours</h3>
        {clinic.properties.ALL_OPENING_HOURS.map(({day_string,opening_hours}) => (
          <p key={Math.random()*10000}>
            <div>{day_string}</div>
            <div>{opening_hours.join(',  ')}</div>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
```